# Outlook 2007 password required to view certain recipients

Tags: outlook-2007

I have run across an odd situation. I have a client machine that is requiring a password to view emails from certain recipients but not others. They are able to log on to Outlook with no problems and can view most emails, just certain ones require passwords.

I have tried to reset the account and verified that all the settings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure these are outlook password request ? I'm asking because one way a password can be prompted when trying to read some incoming mail is if:

- You're using S/MIME
- You received an encrypted message
- Strong private key protection is enabled on the private key needed for decryption

In such a case, the system will prompt for a password every time the private key for your user's certificate is accessed which includes every time an encrypted message is opened.

Comment: Yes, they are outlook password requests. I will verify my settings however, this just started yesterday. The emails in question are from internal accounts and have never required any kind of password before. It is not all internal accounts either, just certain ones. I have not changed any settings and no new accounts have been added to the server. I cant think of anything else...